# SQL query to select only the maximum items?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table: I want to search by UID

```
ID | VID | UID
1  |  1  | 5
1  |  1  | 6
1  |  2  | 6
2  |  3  | 5
2  |  3  | 6
2  |  4  | 6
```

I want to end up with this result:

```
ID | VID | UID
1  |  2  | 6
2  |  4  | 6
```

In other words, only select the entries where the VID is MAX of the UID but keeping in min NID could differ. Something like this I suppose:

```
select * from TABLE where uid = 6 and max(vid)
```

???

But this doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to order by the value in descending order (so the max is at the top), then just select the first result.

```
SELECT t.ID,
       t.VID,
       t.UID 
FROM table t 
WHERE t.ID = 1 
ORDER BY t.VID DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Or do you mean you want *all* rows where t.VID is the highest value? In which case you could do something like this,

```
SELECT t.ID,
       t.VID,
       t.UID
FROM table t
WHERE t.ID = 1
      AND t.VID = (SELECT MAX(VID) FROM table);
```

**EDIT**: Based on the edit to your question, it looks like you just want the max VID value for each ID? If I'm understanding you correctly, then this should give you what you need.

```
SELECT t.ID,
       max(t.VID) as VID,
       t.UID 
FROM table t 
WHERE t.UID = 6 
GROUP BY t.ID
```

Comment: Please see the changes i made.

Comment: Updated based on your changes. I may have misunderstood what you're after though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a subquery.  This should work:

```
select * from TABLE where ID='1' AND VID=(select max(VID) from TABLE)
```

Comment: This is on the right path, but I'm editing the problem, as this doesn't solve all cases for me.

Answer (score 0):

I expect your real-life example is more complicated (at least has more data).

This query will give you the row you want.

SELECT id,vid, uid
FROM TABLE
where id = 1
and vid in (select max(vid) from TABLE where id = 1)

Comment: I won't always just want one entry. I've modified the problem.  Sometimes it could be several different entries with different ids.